# GCC Vector Extensions: AVX2 builtin shuffle crashes when m64 is used

Tags: c, gcc, mingw, vectorization, intrinsics

I have the following program in Mingw, gcc 4.9.2:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

#define VECSIZE 32

typedef char byteVec __attribute__ ((vector_size (VECSIZE))); 

#define PERMLEFT_BVEC (byteVec){63,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30}

byteVec permute(byteVec x, byteVec y) {
    return __builtin_shuffle(x,y,PERMLEFT_BVEC);
}
void print_vec32b(byteVec a) {
    printf("[ ");
    int i; for (i = 0; i < 32; ++i) printf("%d ", a[i]);
    puts("]");
}
int main() {
    byteVec x = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32};
    byteVec y = {11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,110,111,112,113,114,115,116,117,118,119,120,121,122,123,124,125,126,127,88,89,90,91,92};
    byteVec z = permute(x,y);
    print_vec32b(x);
    return 0;
}
```

When I compile this program with -m64, it crashes. With -m32 it works fine. Optimization level doesn't matter. I don't understand what's going on. I've also tried TDM with GCC 5.1.0. Same thing. Anybody have any advice? Is it something screwy with GCC in Windows?

Here is the assembly produced by the compiler (note how the shuffle is turned into a permutation automatically, with vperm2i128 and vpalignr, which is the desired behavior:
[GCC Explorer](https://goo.gl/kVXmfi)

Minimal program: above.
Desired behavior: print permuted byte vector (which it does in 32-bit mode). 
Expected output (works in 32-bit mode):

```
$ gcc nvec.c -m32 -mavx2 -o a.exe && a.exe
[ 92 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 ]
```

Actual result: crash.
Description of crash: immediate crash, windows error reporting bug shows up. No errors or warnings.

Comment: Time to learn to debug!

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve].

Comment: The minimal program is included, as stated. The result is a crash, as stated. The expected result is a permutation of x and y, as stated, which as stated works fine in 32-bit mode. I guess I can be more clear what the output itself is. I will edit the question. I don't understand how to debug this, which is why I came here -- to learn. Thanks.

Comment: "crash" is not a proper error description. That is much like "does not work". Use the debugger and give us more details. And do not post links to binaries. You do not know what they might do to the unaware (remember there are too many people out there who click every link).

Comment: Your vector variables aren't sufficiently aligned on the stack: `vmovdqa YMMWORD PTR [rbp-48], ymm0` - `rbp` is aligned to 32 bytes, but 48 is not divisible by 32.

Comment: There is no binary link, but your advice is good to keep in mind going forward, thanks.

Comment: You're right, it's not aligned! This is weird. Doesn't GCC handle this with the built in vector extensions? How can I fix this?

Comment: `typedef char byteVec __attribute__ ((vector_size (VECSIZE))) __attribute__ ((aligned (32))); ` does not work. I should also mention that the 32-bit version works despite showing `vmovdqa YMMWORD PTR [ebp-56], ymm0` for the same line.

Comment: Try `__m256i` instead of GCC's syntax. But don't get your hopes up. I've heard that mingw has problems with AVX stack-alignment. Though that was a few years ago and I'm not sure if anything has been done about it.

Comment: "Here is the compiled code ..." If that is not the binary, it would be a good idea to rephrase.

Comment: Found this depressing news: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=54412

... This means GCC is no longer compatible with Windows going forward (at least for any of the new and ever-widening processor instructions), until this critical but virtually unnoticed bug is fixed.

Comment: Win10, mingw 5.1.0 x64, your code is running both with and without optimizations. Time to update?)

Comment: Tried official mingw 5.1.0 x64 and TDM's version on Windows 7. Still crashes. It may be possible Windows 10 aligns the stack differently. But there's not much use for a binary that only works on Windows 10

Comment: @user1649948 The OS shouldn't have anything to do with it. In your example, the compiler aligns the stack frame. But then *misaligns* the AVX register. That will crash on any OS. In any case, if you're serious about using AVX on Windows, I recommend a different compiler. Given that it's been broken for years, the MinGW devs are either undermanned or don't care.

Comment: @EvgeniyZh Where did you get this compiler? What were your compilation options?

Comment: @Mysticial, yes, but I want GCC's generic vector support (so at compile time you can just say, "oh yeah, i want mmx so make vectors size 8" or "avx2 plz, make them 32" or compile for arm, powerpc, etc without changing a line. In principle it's awesome -- in practice, meh. But wait, the assembly I showed was generated by GCC explorer under Linux without MingW (before I knew it was a Windows problem). Is that bad too?

Comment: @Mysticial, does this apply tow Mingw-w64? I have not used it much. I remember having some problems with AVX maybe last year but I did not look too much into it.

Comment: @Zboson The last time I've used MingW was 2008-ish.